# VBA Data dump code using transpose and timeline duplication

Tags: performance, vba

The below code ran in 2:26 which is way too slow especially as it's only 1/3rd of the total (the remaining 2/3rd does something very similar just on different sections).  Is there something I can do to speed this up?  RangeCount = 625 and TimelineCount = 156 which are obviously large numbers (total is around 100k rows) but when RangeCount was 200 (30k rows) the code ran in 3 seconds...not sure why it's gone so slow now.

Link to sample: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QHHtWad6_giWETZcAKw8-Qaq7Y6JJ4NX/view?usp=sharing

Edit: I believe I have discovered the issue - the table in Dash Data was an Excel table.  I changed it from being an Excel table to just normal cells and it ran the whole code in 4 seconds.  Can someone explain to me why the table is so slow or how I could improve the speed of it, please??

```
Sub copy_to_dash_data()

Dim i, j As Integer
Dim wsCalcs As Worksheet
Dim wsDashData As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim FirstRow As Long
Dim RangeCount As Long
Dim TimelineCount As Long
Dim LastCell As Long
Dim PasteCell As Long
Dim InvoiceDetailsColumnCount As Long
Dim NamedRange As Range
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim TimeElapsed As String

'timer calculation

StartTime = Timer


'set calcs to manual, disable user events and disable screen updating

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


'setup sheet names for easy reference

Set wsCalcs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Calcs")
Set wsDashData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dash Data")


'find last row and column of Dash Data and clear contents

LastRow = wsDashData.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = Application.Match("P&L Amount", wsDashData.Rows(1), 0)

wsDashData.Range(Cells(2, 1).Address, Cells(LastRow, LastCol).Address).ClearContents


'count the number of rows in the first Calc block and the timeline block

FirstRow = wsCalcs.Range(Names("Invoice_Details")).Row
LastRow = wsCalcs.Range(Names("Invoice_Details")).Rows.Count + FirstRow - 1
RangeCount = wsCalcs.Range(Names("Invoice_Details")).Rows.Count - 1

TimelineCount = wsCalcs.Range(Names("Months_and_Years_Timeline")).Columns.Count - 1


'month start, month end and year rows from Calcs values transfer to Dash Data a number of times equal to the number of rows in the Calc block (e.g. number of invoices)

PasteCell = Application.Match("Month Start", wsDashData.Rows(1), 0)

For i = 1 To RangeCount
    wsDashData.Range(Cells(2 + (TimelineCount * (i - 1)), PasteCell).Address, Cells(1 + (TimelineCount * i), PasteCell + 2).Address) = _
        Application.Transpose(wsCalcs.Range(Names("Months_and_Years_Timeline")))
Next i


'enable events and screen updating

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Calculate

'code complete!

TimeElapsed = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")
MsgBox ("Code complete in " & TimeElapsed), vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the code here in the question indented the same way it is in the VBA module?

Comment: Yes... is that a problem?

Comment: No, just checking.

Comment: You need to describe exactly what the code is doing.  Sample data or a mock workbook download would help.  Does `Months_and_Years_Timeline` values change during each iteration of the loop?

Comment: This snippet takes the months and years timeline which is just the month start, month end and year for every month from 2018 to 2030 (156 columns) and transposes it rangecount number of times (625 times) into a data table in the dash data tab.

Comment: Sample data here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QHHtWad6_giWETZcAKw8-Qaq7Y6JJ4NX/view?usp=sharing

No, the Months and Years Timeline doesn't change so it's just copying and pasting data 625 times essentially.  The other data that comes in does change with each iteration but I thought this was the easiest bit to explain.